# Bounded type parameters in Vala

Tags: vala

In Java you can have something like this

```
class MyClass<E extends A> { ...
```

In C#

```
class MyClass<E> where E : A { ...
```

Anything similar in Vala?

Answer (score 2):

No, not supported in Vala.

[This](https://github.com/GNOME/vala/blob/5b024e44077b6738855b6b2e92d913b75fda3444/vala/valatokentype.vala) is all available keywords in the language Vala, and the "where" specifier is not there.

[Here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=668474) is a filled bug to ask for this feature.

I've had need for constraints as well, in the and I had to change my design to use a normal generic type.