# Is there any support for a mixture of parametric and subtype polymorphism with constraints in Vala?

Tags: inheritance, vala, parametric-polymorphism

One of my personal favourite features of C# is the ability to mix parametric and subtype polymorphism (Generics and inheritance). But I can't find any documentation for Vala stating this is available, or any discussions saying this is unavailable or upcoming. Can anyone give me a definitive answer, and a source saying it is, is not or will be available in the future?

For a brief example of what I mean in case theres any confusion:

```
namespace Animals
{
    public interface Animal{
        void say_something();
    }

    public abstract class Canine : Animal{
        public void say_something(){
                stdout.printf("Woof!");
        }
    }

    public interface AnimalSpecialist<T> where T : Animal{
    }

    public interface DogSpecialist<T> : AnimalSpecialist<T> where T : Canine{
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bounded type parameters in Vala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692468/bounded-type-parameters-in-vala)

Comment: It is. I just never identified it, b cause I couldn't recall the word for it

Answer (score 1):

With a few small changes your example code compiles with valac.

```
namespace Animals
{
    public interface Animal {
        public abstract void say_something();
    }

    public abstract class Canine : Animal {
        public void say_something(){
                stdout.printf("Woof!");
        }
    }

    public interface AnimalSpecialist<T> {
    }

    public interface DogSpecialist<T> : AnimalSpecialist<T> {
    }
}
```

The one thing that Vala does not support is type parameter constraints (`where T …`).

Other than that both parametric and subtype polymorphism are supported.

One thing to always keep in mind is that Vala code is directly translated into C code, so there are some limitations to parametric polymorphism that you will notice, especially when using generics with non nullable value types.

I can't comment on variance (covariance and contravariance) and how that is handled.

Comment: While your answer is excellent, i knew that bit was possible. What I probably wasn't clear enough about was: the constraint part is particularly interesting :)

Comment: The thing is: without the constraints, AnimalSpecialist does not know that T can do: `say_something()` and DogSpecialist does not know whatever arbitrary thing is shared between all Canines

Comment: It would be nice to have and there is an issue open for it here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala/issues/271